# divergent or convergent series ? for every 'a' real number

Tags: sequences-and-series

let be the function

$$ g(a)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(an)}{n} $$

with $ f(x)=x-[x] $ fractional part of the number

'a' is a real number , then how could i compute if this series is diverget or not ? is differentiable at every point in the real line ?

Comment: I don't think this is everywhere differentiable.

Comment: It diverges on $\Bbb{Q} \setminus \Bbb{Z}$, which kills any question about differentiability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always divergent if $\alpha \in R-Z$.
The key part is to show it diverges for $\alpha$ irrational (other cases are easy).
In this case, one has to use the fact that ${n\alpha}$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. In words if we look at the set ${ n\alpha, (n+1)\alpha, ..., (2n-1)\alpha }$
then (roughly) half of them will be $>= 1/2$.
Then one has:
$\sum _{n=1}^{n=k}{\alpha n}/n >= \sum \sum_{k=2^l}^{2^(l+1)} \alpha k/k$ 
Now, using the observation above each inner sum is at least $1/2\sum _{k=2^l + 2^(l-1)}^{2^(l+1)}1/k$ which is around $1/2 log(2^{l+1}/{2^l + 2^{l-1}})$ which is $1/2log(2/(1+ 1/2))$ which is of course separated from $0$.